# how to remove words with exactly 2 characters using sed command

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am solving a shell job which consists of decrypting a code. I treated the text and arrived at a time when I separated the words in each different line, that is, one word per line. I have some clues that 3 character words represent letters and 2 characters represent symbols.
I want to put the 3 character words in a variable and then replace these words with letters in frequency order (starting with 'e', and so on).
My wish is to exclude words that are two characters long and keep only words that are 3 characters long.

I've tried sed in a lot of ways by modifying the code,

```
sed -r 's / \ b \ w {6,} \ s? \ b // g'
```

Also there is a big problem all words that have 3 characters consequently also have 2 characters, but I want to exclude only those that have exactly 2 characters.

This is the example of the file I have so far

```
apb
aph
api
api
app
app
app
app
app
app
dg
dh
dh
di
di
di
di
ea
ea
ea
```

for the file entry above I would have to have:

```
apb
aph
api
api
app
app
app
app
app
app
```

Comment: If you have one word per line, with no whitespace, try `sed '/^..$/d'`

Comment: You have to indent code with 4 spaces, or put triple backticks on the lines before and after it.

Comment: I don't remember where I learned about it, but [here's a good introduction](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a few ways, assuming the input file is called *23.txt*:

1. `grep -v '^..$' 23.txt` shows lines that aren't 2 chars long.
2. `grep '^...$' 23.txt` shows only lines that are 3 chars long.
3. `sed -n '/^..$/!p' 23.txt` prints lines that aren't 2 chars long.
4. `sed '/^..$/d' 23.txt` deletes lines that aren't 2 chars long from output.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following. If you are ok with `awk` solution.

```
awk 'length($0)==2{next} 1' Input_file
or
awk 'length($0)!=2' Input_file
```

OR(as per David C. Rankin sir's comment adding following)

```
awk '/^...$/' Input_file
or
awk '!/^..$/' Input_file
```

Comment: Or shorter, `awk '/^...$/' Input_file` (though technically this isn't removing the 2-char lines)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Thank you for adding this in comments, I have added them in my post too, cheers.

Comment: `length($0)==2{next} 1` is the same as `length!=2`.

Comment: `how to remove words with exactly 2 characters using sed command`. This `awk '/^...$/'` will keep only three charters, so technically wrong compare to the request.  This will only keep 3 characters and remove all other.

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`

```
awk 'length($0)!=2' file
```

Answer (score 0):

When you only have lines with 2 or 3 characters, select the lines with at least 3 characters:

```
grep ... inputfile
```